# Geometrical place with circles...

Tags: geometry

How to find the geometrical place of all centers of a circles that tangent from inside to the circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and the $y$-axis? (Suppose that $x,y\geq 0$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $d_1$ be the line through $A(1,0)$ parallel to the $y$-axis (denoted by $d_0$ in what follows), and let $O(0,0)$ be the center  of the circle (denoted by ${\cal C}$). The geometrical place ${\cal P}$ of all centers of a circles that are internally tangent  the circle and also to   $d_0$ is the arc of the parabola of Focus $O$ and directrix $d_1$, which is contained inside the circle.

Indeed, A point $M$ belongs to ${\cal P}$ if and only if it is inside ${\cal C}$ and  $d(M,d_0)$ is equal to radius of the circle centered at $M$ and internally tangent to ${\cal C}$, that is $1-d(M,O)$. But the equality $d(M,d_0)=1-d(M,O)$ is equivalent to
$$d(M,O)=1-d(M,d_0)=d(M,d_1).$$
and this is equivalent to the fact that $M$ belongs to parabola of Focus $O$ and directrix $d_1$. which is the announced result.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the radius is r. Then it is :

$1-r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Distance from centre of first circle is difference of radii.